# How can I connect through HTTP in Kotlin/Native iOS development?

Tags: ios, kotlin

I tried to get a web page in Kotlin/Native with iOS platform, but it didn't work.
Please tell me where is the problem.

I created the project with Gradle and `build.gradle` contains:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.21'
}
```

Here are the codes.

```
package sample

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(WebGateway.get("https://www.google.com/"))
}
```

```
package sample

import platform.Foundation.*
import platform.darwin.*

actual object WebGateway {
    actual fun get(urlString: String): String {
        val semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

        var components = NSURLComponents(urlString)
        val url = components.URL
        var result: String = ""
        val config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        config.waitsForConnectivity = true
        config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 300.0
        val session = NSURLSession.sessionWithConfiguration(
            config, null, NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        )

        val task = session
            .dataTaskWithURL(url!!) { nsData: NSData?, nsurlResponse: NSURLResponse?, nsError: NSError? ->
                nsData?.run { result = toString() }
                println(nsData)
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
            }

        task.resume()
        session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        return result
    }
}
```

After building the application, `main.kexe` was created.

I expected the Google web page HTML is printed in standard output by executing the application.
But the actual is:

```
 % ./main.kexe
```

It doesn't show anything.
The program stops at `dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`.

After executing the application, `task.state` became `NSURLSessionTaskStateCompleted`, but the program doesn't show anything or finish.

When I changed the `session` to `NSURLSession.sessionWithConfiguration(config)`, I got the following output.

```
 % ./main.kexe
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException: illegal attempt to access non-shared sample.WebGateway.$<anonymous>$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$0@f6f058e8 from other thread
        at 0   main.kexe                           0x000000010039c3c3 ThrowIllegalObjectSharingException + 595
        at 1   main.kexe                           0x00000001003b9d6d -[KotlinObjectHolder ref] + 141
        at 2   main.kexe                           0x00000001003c9524 platform_Foundation_kniBridge11046 + 148
        at 3   main.kexe                           0x00000001003ca18c __platform_Foundation_kniBridge11045_block_invoke + 108
        at 4   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff4cd80763 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
        at 5   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff4cd8016c __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 172
        at 6   Foundation                          0x00007fff50243a47 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
        at 7   Foundation                          0x00007fff5024394e -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
        at 8   Foundation                          0x00007fff50218f7a -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 686
        at 9   Foundation                          0x00007fff5024367f __NSOQSchedule_f + 227
        at 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aef3d4f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        at 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aef4dcb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        at 12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aef75d8 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 427
        at 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7aef6c7a _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 718
        at 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7af02d1a _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 325
        at 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7af034b1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 90
        at 16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7b1346ee _pthread_wqthread + 619
        at 17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7b134415 start_wqthread + 13
zsh: abort      ./main.kexe
```

When I changed `session` to `NSURLSession.sharedSession()`, the same error appeared.

Comment: Any success on this?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin native expects the callback to be called on the main thread.
This is how the native HTTP request is implemented in Kotlin conf spinner app.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinconf-spinner/blob/master/clients/ios/src/iosMain/kotlin/platformUtils.kt

Comment: Can also call put the request inside a NSOperationQueue.mainQueue.addOperationWithBlock { }